# Can I make both x axis and y axis a string in google charts?

Tags: html, google-visualization

I want to have on the bottom a string of dates, and on the y axis I want a string of rankings (ex: 1st Place, 2nd Place, 3rd Place)

Heres what I tried to do, but it is not working.

```
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Draw line chart progress report
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

  // Draw pie chart rankings report
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieChart);

  // Callback that draws line chart for progress report
  function drawLineChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'comp NY', 'comp NJ'],
      ['10/2/2014',  '1st Place',      '4th Place'],
      ['11/21/2015',  '11th Place',      '46th Place'],
      ['12/1/2016',  '66th Place',       '11th Place'],
      ['1/15/2017',  '10 Place',      '5th Place']
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Dancer\'s competition placement',
      width: 600,
      height: 550,
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

when I do this the chart doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by "vAxis" Option parameter that Google charts offer.

Find this code (amends done to your code) where I have used the same.

```
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Draw line chart progress report
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

// Draw pie chart rankings report
// google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieChart);

// Callback that draws line chart for progress report
function drawLineChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'comp NY', 'comp NJ'],
    ['10/2/2014', 1, 4,],
    ['11/21/2015', 11,46],
    ['12/1/2016', 66, 11],
    ['1/15/2017', 10, 5]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Dancer\'s competition placement',
    width: 600,
    height: 550,
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    vAxis: { ticks: [{ v: 1, f: '1st Place'}, {v: 10, f: '10th Place'}, {v: 20, f: '20th Place'}, {v: 30, f: '30th Place'}, {v: 40, f: '40th Place'}, {v: 50, f: '50th Place'}, {v: 60, f: '60th Place'}, {v: 70, f: '70th Place'}]}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

You can find more about customizing the axis on google charts on this documentation link => https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes

PS: You cannot enter sting in the value field for the graph!

Comment: Thank you but this will be difficult because I’m trying to get the placement from the database. And in the database placements are entered as “1st place” and not “1”.. is there a way I can get just the number alone from the database?

Comment: You will have to Loop through the values that you are getting from the database and clean them. You can do them either on the server side (e.g. Using PHP) or using javascript.  Examples for both of them can be found as mentioned. 

PHP => 
$string_record = '1st place';
$number_record = (int) filter_var($string_record, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

Javascript => 
var string_record = '1st place';
var number_record = string_record.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);